# CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-animation, catransaction

While my app is running, I often get the following warning:

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted `CATransaction`;
>   set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.

Does anyone have an idea why this message shows up sometimes?
Is it possible that it's causing a crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess anywhere in your code is an uncommitted CATransaction, maybe this is what you have missed:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
[CATransaction commit];
```

taken from here [CoreAnimation uncommitted CATransaction warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882931/coreanimation-uncommitted-catransaction-warning)